# Solr ContentSearch returning too many results for a string comparison that should return just one

Tags: content-search, solr, indexing

I have a very straightforward ContentSearch issue.

My code is as follows:

```
var filter = PredicateBuilder.True<PersonObject>();
filter = filter
   .And(i => i.Email == "my.email@address.com");
```

*(...standard ContentSearch code follows...)*

Where the `Email` field is defined as:

```
[IndexField("email_t")]
public virtual string Email { get; set; }
```

The index is populated correctly: going on the SOLR web interface and performing the following query:

```
query?q=email_t:"my.email@address.com"
```

results in the one record with said email address being correctly returned.

Interestingly enough, the Search.log has this entry associated to the above search:

```
?q=email_t:(my.email@address.com)&rows=1&fl=*,score&fq=_indexname:(sitecore_web_index)&wt=xml&sort=sortorder_tl asc
```

Which sounds pretty much spot-on. So why this search is returning *every single *PersonObject** and not just the one with the specified email?

**QUESTION**(s)

What am I doing wrong that is causing multiple results to be returned?
Are the information I provided enough to troubleshoot this issue?

Comment: If I recall, it has to do with tokenization of the contents of that field. So when you issue a search for `my.email@address.com`, internally Solr is searching for `my`, `email`, `address`, and `com`. Which would return (almost) everything because most email addresses probably have `com` in them.

We resolved this issue by creating a custom computed field for emails (which apparently doesn't get tokenized) that just stores the email value and searching against that field intead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how `text` fields work, it's a tokenized search.. If you are looking for an exact string match, you should be using `returnType="string"` in your index configuration. Beware as well that you should not be using `_t` in your code as that hardcodes the Solr field type. You should also change that in your code to just `[IndexField("email")]`. This should be all you need.

Comment: Do I have to specifically declare `email` (or `email_s`) as part of the index configuration?

Comment: This worked for me - I only had to add `<field fieldName="email" returnType="string" storageType="yes">MyProject.ComputedFields.ParsedValue, MyProject</field>` to my custom IndexConfiguration.

Comment: @EmanueleCiriachi Ah yes. It is always best to explicitly specify the `returnType`. Also, never specify the suffix as Sitecore will determine it automatically for you. `email` is sufficient (not `_s` or `_t`).